# How to open a html file from a help menu button

Tags: java, html, eclipse, swing

I am try to open a javadoc html file with my new application, however I can not get the javadoc file to open, I have a class name OpenUri, which when called is supposed to open the javadoc:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OpenUri extends JFrame {

public static void openWebpage(URI uri) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void openWebpage(URL url) {
    try {
        openWebpage(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am then calling and using this class from another class called Menu, where the help button has an action listener, etc. However when I run the code and press the help button, no javadoc appears, ie, it doesn't open the document, ie, nothing happens, no window, nothing ?
The only way I can open it is manually, by clicking on it in eclipse, here is the specific code from the Menu class I am Using:

```
//Help
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        helpMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/Users/howhowhows/workspace/OPTICS_DROP_MENU/doc/index.html");
                    OpenUri.openWebpage(uri);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what I am doing wrong, ie what I need to add/change, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You beat me to the edit  And i WILL not buy this record.

Comment: Not that it solves anything, but why `OpenUri extends JFrame`?

Comment: @mplungjan is it scratched?

Comment: I see lots of edits being undone. Maybe try not to edit in parallel?

Comment: @Pshemo the application that I'm writing is a GUI, so I thought that "OpenUri extends JFrame" would be the right way to implement the class, any thoughts?

Comment: `Child extends Parent` means that Child class can be treated as representation of Parent (it's "is a" relationship). `OpenUri` doesn't look like class which should be treated as `JFrame`. We don't show this frame, and it doesn't even hold any other Swing components like JLabel or JButton, so there is no point in it extending it. Also in case of JFrame extending it is considered by many Swing programmers as bad practice if you don't need to customize it (like override its `paintComponent` method).

Answer (score 2):

Have you downloaded and tried the demo code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).

When I used that code and pasted your URI into the text field no window is displayed and I get a "System cannot find the file" message as expected.

When I then enter a simple URI that I know exists: "c:/java/a.html" the browser opens as expected.

So I suggest you start with  known working code and see if your URI works. If it does work then the problem is your code, so compare the working code to your code to see what the difference is. If it doesn't work then the problem is the URI.

If you still have problems then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Given that your OPenURI class extends JFrame for no reason we don't know what other strange things you might be doing in your code.

Comment: Thanks, for your help, but can you please post the code you are using which opens your "c:/java/a.html" page, so I can test it against my page. Cheers. c",)

Comment: @benlopas, I gave you the code. It is in the tutorial. You need to download the demo code from the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks @camickr , I should be able to adapt this to my GUI, I will  add a SSCCE , if I get really stuck though, Cheers, +1.  c",)